# Generate number like auto icrement with zero

Tags: php

Generate number like auto icrement with zero
I wont generate ordinal number example from 0 to 999 but just 3 digit, from 3 digits zero like this

```
000
001
002
003
...
999
```

how create this with php?

Comment: `for` and `sprintf`?

Comment: @cmorrissey thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_pad and a for-loop:

```
    for($i=0; $i<=999;$i++) {
        echo str_pad($i, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```